# How to fix Error http response code failure in android webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have created a website using wix.com and when I click on login with facebook on my android webview it says net::Err_http_response_code_failure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UZ6H.jpg)

Comment: Does the same url work on the browser?

Comment: If I click on login with facebook, then it works, if i copy that url then it have buttons of login with facebook and google and buttons doesn't return any value..,

Comment: Can you paste the url?

Comment: Www.shiscab.com click on car and login with facebook and login with google available there, thanku

Comment: @HarpreetSingh Did you get any solution for this ?